# Function runs even thou it's not called

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm looking for a way to clean my DB with a button on a html-page (.php). I have a code that's working OK, but every time I go in to the page the function is cleaning my DB without me pushing the button.

Here is my code

```
<button id="checkoutbutton" onclick="cleanDb()">Clean DB</button>
<script>
function cleanDb()
{alert("<?php clean();?>")}
</script>
<?php
function clean()
{
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","rss","Habb0") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $db=mysql_select_db("kalender",$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $sql='DELETE FROM `bilder` WHERE `stop` < now()';
 mysql_query($sql);

 echo "Databasen är rensad från gamla bilder";}
?>
```

Please help me!

Comment: you are calling function in php so when the page is loaded your `clean()` would call. if you want to perform it by click button. call a ajax function for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is parsed on the server side, JavaScript is parsed on the client side. Any PHP operation will run first, before any javascript (Not considering AJAX).

Comment: @user223062 Use ajax or a form or a hyperlink. Make a seprate PHP page that will do the db operation. Make your button request that page.

Comment: @user223062 making PHP to interact like this is not a simple thing, you need sufficient knowledge about how HTTP is working.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, but I am not using javascript. In your case you should consider AJAX. But 2nd option is as follow

```
<form action="" method="post">
<button id="checkoutbutton" onclick="cleanDb()" name="clebtn">Clean DB</button>
</form>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['clebtn']))
 {
  function clean()
   {
    // your code
   }

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must call **ajax** for it like this

```
<button id="checkoutbutton" onclick="cleanDb()">Clean DB</button>
<div id="result_content"></div>
<script>
function cleanDb()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
            // do your task for result
        }
    }

    var url="clean_db.php";

    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);

    xmlhttp.send();
}   
</script>
```

and a PHP File **clean_db.php**

```
<?php
clean();
echo "db has been cleaned";

function clean()
{
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","rss","Habb0") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $db=mysql_select_db("kalender",$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $sql='DELETE FROM `bilder` WHERE `stop` < now()';
 mysql_query($sql);

 echo "Databasen är rensad från gamla bilder";}
?>
```

Comment: Nice one, I only remember how to write AJAX with jQuery.